What would happen if somebody was administered caffeine while sleeping?
I know that drinking caffeine before sleep can disrupt your sleep and REM cycle, but I was wondering what would happen if hypothetically someone slept for 8 or so hours before being administered a dose of (just to give a number) 50mg of caffeine through an IV.  Would they be woken up?  If they stayed asleep, what would happen?  Thanks everybody!

Could you tell us what the purpose of the question is? In what context is this likely to happen and for what reason? If you're writing a work of fiction, then our [writing.se] site may be of interest to you, and our [worldbuilding.se] site can help you with hypotheticals - but be sure take their tour, read their help center and to include a worldbuilding context.

There is no reason why caffeine would wake anyone up who is already asleep. Caffeine works because it's shape is very similar to adenosine molecules, they can therefore fit into the same receptors and prevent adenosine from binding. Adenosine is part of the reason we feel sleepy late in the evening and so preventing its binding like caffeine does will reduce that feeling of drowsiness. This hypothetical scenario could in theory lead to the person feeling less rested the day after because it would cause more adenosine to stick around afterwards. This reason is also why caffeine very early in the morning can make people feel drowsy later and is a bad idea overall.
Source for the basics:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3153505/
